# How get full short date by culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, culture

this code return to me `'M/d/yyyy'` but I need `'mm/dd/yyyy'` how do this?

```
((CultureInfo)Session["culture"]).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
```

Comment: Not sure to understand: you want to get the format from the culture, and you expect a fixed, hard-coded format to be returned?

Comment: If you want it to return the specific format you need to set up it first. (But it gives me no sense). `(CultureInfo)Session["culture"]).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "mm/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: No, I need format not Dec/21/2012 and I need 12/21/2012

Comment: @simplydenis - What is `Session["culture"]` and where does it get set?

Comment: You need to clarify a bit better. If you always want `"MM/dd/yyyy'`, then you can simply skip `CultureInfo` using a `ToString(string format)` overload. However if you need to some how customize a culture's format string without completely replacing it, you will need to provide more detail as to what that entails.

Answer (score 1):

That dosn't make much since... The pattern you want is for a specific culture..
For instance:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

Will return `mm/dd/yyyy` but

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

will return `dd/mm/yyyy`.

From the code you added, it's not very clear - it seems you're getting a specific culture but then want to override the `ShortDatePattern`...

If this is true, why use the Culture received in the session in the first place? Use whatever pattern you want without regarding the culture. 
e.g. `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

(Anyways, it IS possible to override, as `ShortDatePattern` can be set, just like @mipe34 showed in the comments)

Comment: Did you mean for them both to be en-US?

Answer (score 0):

You can override how dates are displayed by specifying the template you want in the `ToString` method:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) //Will display "12/21/2012"
```

You appear to be using a `CultureInfo` object, which contains default formats (and other cultural information such as currency) and is provided by the operating system.

Calling `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` by itself will use the format specified by `ShortDatePattern` in the current thread's culture, which can be set with something like:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to change the property? This is simple:

```
((CultureInfo)Session["culture"]).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

However, if the `CultureInfo` happens to be read-only, it will throw run-time. In that case maybe you can assign a new `CultureInfo` object? If you can, do it like this:

```
// get reference
var ci = (CultureInfo)Session["culture"];
// clone and reassign to get rid of read-only:
ci = (CultureInfo)(ci.Clone());
// change property:
ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
// make read-only again
ci = CultureInfo.ReadOnly(ci);
// assign back to your "source":
Session["culture"] = ci;
```

After that, when people call `someDateTimeValue.ToShortDateString()` on some new thread whose `CurrentCulture` is taken from `Session["culture"]`, they will get your new format.

Note: `"m"` or `"mm"` is *minutes*, and `"M"` or `"MM"` is *months*. Also `"/"` is the `DateSeparator` of the culture (which might translate to a dash (`-`) or something else in some cultures).